# Can’t change the system date in a test

Tags: apex, unit-test

The code below is a nightly scheduled job and part of the finished method which should only be enqueued once per week. The problem is, how to test it because I can't change the system date in a test environment to make currentWeekday == mySettings?

Does anyone have a thought of how to test it?

```
Integer currentWeekday = DatetimeUtils.getDayOfWeekPacific();

Decimal mySetting = [metadata type record field value];

    if(currentWeekday == mySetting) {
      System.enqueueJob(new someQueueable());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally prefer the use of a variable that I can override in the test:

```
@TestVisible static Integer currentWeekday = DatetimeUtils.getDayOfWeekPacific();

...

Decimal mySetting = [metadata type record field value];

if(currentWeekday == mySetting) {
  System.enqueueJob(new someQueueable());
}
```

The trick is that in your unit test, you can set the value beforehand:

```
SomeClassName.currentWeekDay = 5;
SomeClassName.doSomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test.isRunningTest()` to handle this for testing. This will help you to create test data which will be used for testing purposes.

For more information, refer[Test.isRunningTest()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205831&type=1)

```
Integer currentWeekday = 0; 
if(Test.isRunningTest()){
//define your weekday
    currentWeekday = 7; //for an example
}
else
{
    currentWeekday = DatetimeUtils.getDayOfWeekPacific();
}

Decimal mySetting = [metadata type record field value];

    if(currentWeekday == mySetting) {
      System.enqueueJob(new someQueueable());
    }
```

Comment: While that works it limits your ability to write negative or alternate test methods and it does not allow other tests to not run the code as a general patter